# Kakfa-console-producer format for sending key and a file

Tags: file, apache-kafka

I am trying to send a file to my java application via kafka-console-producer.bat 
I found out that the proper format to send a file is as below :

```
kafka-console-producr.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic topic_name < C:\file.txt
```

What I want to do is pass a key along with the file.
I do know the proper format for sending key with single line messages.

Is there any way to send a key along with the above format?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're wanting to get data from a file into Kafka beyond just a sandbox setup, use something like Kafka Connect with https://www.confluent.io/hub/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the kafka-consoler-producer with the properties `parse.key=true` and `key.separator=[mySeparator]`. An example is given here:

```sh
/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test --property "parse.key=true" --property "key.separator=:::" < C:\file.txt
```

You only need to ensure that the `key.separator` matches the one given in your text file.

Comment: Actually, my problem is to read the whole file contents. Also  it just reads the file path instead of  the file contents along with the key

Comment: just add ` < C:\file.txt` as you correctly did in your question. I have updated my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: So they key in this case will be inside the file?

Comment: Yes, the lines in the file.txt should look like `key1:::value1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked for me. 
I was under the impression that I could specify a key and then the file to be consumed. Is there such a provision available? (Just curious) 

P.S. Hope you are safe during this quarantine time.

Comment: not sure about the key outside of the file. That sounds like a new question to be asked :)